# SwiftUI Providing destination for NavigationLink in the view init resulting in "Type 'any View' cannot conform to 'View'"

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationview

I am trying to make a `NavigationLink` and provide the destination in its init but I am receiving an error:

> Type 'any View' cannot conform to 'View'

```
struct MenuButton: View {
    
    let iconName: String
    let destination: () -> any View
    
    var body: some View {

        NavigationLink { //Type 'any View' cannot conform to 'View'
            destination()
        } label: {
            Image(systemName: iconName)
                .foregroundColor(.pink)
                .padding()
        }
    }
}


struct MenuBar: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            MenuButton(iconName: "gearshape") {
                //providing destination here
                let user = User(firstName: "Mock", lastName: "Data", dateStarted: 142356345)
                return HomeView(viewModel: HomeViewModel(user: user))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I switch `any View` to `some View` in the destination declaration, I receive an error:

> Property declares an opaque return type, but has no initializer expression from which to infer an underlying type

Comment: You have to add “@ViewBuilder” and use “some View”

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You just need to make `MenuButton` generic over some type (say `V`) that conforms to `View`:

```
struct MenuButton<V: View>: View {
    
    let iconName: String
    let destination: () -> V
    
    var body: some View {

        NavigationLink { 
            destination()
        } label: {
            Image(systemName: iconName)
                .foregroundColor(.pink)
                .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Another option I found is wrapping destination() in AnyView:

```
 struct MenuButton: View {
    
    let iconName: String
    let destination: () -> any View
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink {
            AnyView(destination())
        } label: {
            Image(systemName: iconName)
                .foregroundColor(.pink)
                .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: AnyView is highly discouraged you should watch Demystify SwiftUI

Comment: Do you have any other solution?

Comment: I linked it above with the duplicate question link. You can also watch the video for more.